# Render one template (no ng-repeat)

Tags: json, angularjs, templating, ionic-framework

I am just starting off with angular, but basically I want to render one set of templates with ng repeat:

```
<ion-item ng-repeat="item in items" ng-click="loadSingle(item)">
  Hello, {{item.name}}!
</ion-item>
```

and then later I want to render the object in a different template if someone clicks on it:

```
<div>
  <h1>{{ item.name }}</h1>
  <h2>{{ item.detail }}</h2>
</div>
```

How do I do this? With jQuery/underscore I would just have the separate template loaded and feed it the json object (item) but I can't seem to find any documentation on how to do the templating without the ng-repeat. I'm a little confused. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would define `loadSingle()` as a method that would put the specific item onto the scope. Then I would define another section in the HTML to display the selected item.

JavaScript

```
app.controller('ctrl', function($scope){

   $scope.loadSingle = function(item){
      $scope.selectedItem = item;
   }

});
```

HTML

```
<div ng-show="selectedItem">
  <h1>{{ selectedItem.name }}</h1>
  <h2>{{ selectedItem.detail }}</h2>
</div>
```